# Overriding iOS system volume to play alarm

Tags: ios, audio, overriding, volume

I have an alarm application and if user reduces the phone volume using the hardware keys the alarm volume also gets affected. I have noticed few of the other alarm applications raising alarm even if system volume is zero or muted. How i can achieve the same? iam currently using both AVAudioPlayer & MPMusicPlayerController for playing audio.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `volume` on both `MPMusicPlayerController` and on `AVAudioPlayer`.

For example:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1.0;
```